# Не работает шроткод WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Вписую шорткод в контенте поста но он не выводится, но если вывожу через do_shortcode то все нормально. Как сделать чтоб в поле "ТЕКСТ" я ввел шоткод и все работало. По [ссылке](http://nateko.oscorp.pro/slajd-galerei-1/) видно как работае в моем случае.

Comment: решил замеил вывод  на apply_filters('the_content',get_the_content())

Comment: Через плагин я всегда вывожу, такое решение устроит?

Comment: @ Валерий Емельянов, каким образом?просто у меня такая же проблема...